# Excluding groups from dataframe based on count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
                             Attribute
                                 count
Crop Type     Harvest Season
Barley        Spring                25
Corn (Grain)  Spring               655
              Winter                 1
Corn (Silage) Spring                 6
Cotton        Spring                 5
Peas          Spring                 3
Canola        Spring               169
              Winter               164
Soybeans      Spring               541
              Winter                 2
Sugar beet    Spring                82
Sunflower     Spring               637
              Winter                 1
Wheat         Spring               253
              Winter               451
```

I have a dataframe `df` where I counted the number of each group based on the foll. code:
`df[['Crop Type', 'Harvest Season']].groupby(['Crop Type', 'Harvest Season']).agg(['count'])`

The output of this code is the dataframe above.

How can I exclude groups from the original dataframe where the count is less than 30?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: If you look at the multiple conditions section of the first answer just use half of it to check for < 30

Comment: No it does not answer, I am using the results of a count on a groupby operation to exclude rows from the original dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change logic - select all rows if count of groups is greater or same like `30` by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for repeat aggregate counts in `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.groupby(['Crop Type', 'Harvest Season'])['Crop Type'].transform('count').ge(30)]
```

Comment: thanks! Why did you do `df[df.groupby(['Crop Type', 'Harvest Season'])['Crop Type'].transform('count').ge(30)]` and not `df[df.groupby(['Crop Type', 'Harvest Season'])['Crop Type', 'Harvest Season'].transform('count').ge(30)]`

Comment: @user308827 - Because if use `df.groupby(['Crop Type', 'Harvest Season'])['Crop Type', 'Harvest Season'].transform('count')` get output 2 columns Dataframe, for filter is necessary only `Series`. So if use `df.groupby(['Crop Type', 'Harvest Season'])['Crop Type', 'Harvest Season'].transform('count').ge(30)` get boolean DataFrame with same values in rows (if no missing data, because `count` exclude them)